# Count the number of Substrings which are Palindromes

Tags: python, string, algorithm, palindrome

I am currently attempting to solve a programming question featured on Hackerreank, (Link Here -> https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/count-palindromes).

The question defines a string as composed of lower case characters ( a through z )

K is a number I am provided as input

I am supposed to find the smallest string( definition above ), that  contains K palindrome substrings. (Palindrome is a sequence which when reversed will give the same sequence).

Ok, this makes sense. Now, here's my approach

Suppose I have a string "aaaa", this has 10 palindrome substrings of the form
a,a,a,a
aa,aa,aa
aaa,aaa
aaaa.
 (Since characters at different indexes are considered unique.)

So if K was given as 10, then the smallest length of string that has 10 palindrome substrings is 4. Hence the answer is 4 (This detail can also be found on the link)

Now I have an approach to solving this problem, which is not giving me the right result.

Suppose the substring length is N, I will obtain the smallest possible value of N, if it contains all the same characters

If I assume this, then the number of:

Size 1 palindrome substrings = N

Size 2 palindrome substrings = N-1

Size 3 palindrome substrings = N-2

..

..

..

Size N palindrome substrings = 1

The number of palindrome substrings can be calculated using this code

```
index = N
total = 0
while N > 0:
    total += N   
    N-=1
```

Step by Step, this code is simply computing the sum of natural numbers from 1 till N

Hence (N * N+1) / 2 is the number of palindrome substrings a number can have. Therefore for a particular N, is (N * N+1) / 2 is equal to K, then N is the answer.

Now a sample case input K is 17

But N * N+1 / 2 will never give a N (Natual Number)

Can anyone tell what is the mistake in my approach. All help is appreciated :) and sorry for the long question

P.S  : I dont really need a solution to the problem, I just want to figure out whats wrong with my algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong since you are trying to count the number of all substrings in a string. "Suppose the substring length is N, I will obtain the smallest possible value of N, if it contains all the same characters". It's where the mistake lies. As the distribution N*(N+1)/2 does not cover entire set of natural number systems, there will be several values of K that they could ask and you cannot cover for it. 17 is such value.

```
aaaa -> it has 10 palindrome substrings.
aaaaa -> it has 15 palindrome substrings.
aaaaaa -> it has 21 palindrome substrings.
```

As you could see, the number of palindrome substrings jumps from 15 with N = 5 to 21 with N = 6. Hence something like HAVING EXACTLY 17 palindrome substrings cannot possibly be expressed by strings with only one character.

However, if you cleverly add in another letter (or several letters) appropriately, you could change this situation. E.g.

```
aaaaabb -> it has 18 palindrome substrings. ( Added b,b,bb)
```

Hope it gives you some directions. I have not figured out the answer myself, but I think the trick lies in adding letters into your original string of one character, since the example above (incidentally) also used the minimum string.

Another example:

```
aaaaabbc -> (minimum ?) string that has EXACTLY 19 palindrome substrings.
```

G00d luck :)

Comment: Thanks. I see where the fault in my logic lies. I was so focused on reducing N that I forgot to take into consideration how other factors. I'll come up with an algorithm soon enough ;) . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The formula for your sum is neither (N * N+1)/2 nor N * N+1 / 2.
The right formula is (N*(N+1))/2. This is always a natural number, becuase either N or (N+1) is even. Thus, (N*(N+1)) is even and (N*(N+1))/2 is a natural number.

Comment: When I said N*N+1 /2, I meant it is (N*(N+1))/2. Sorry :) .  And I meant to say that I cannot arrive at an integer N value when K is 17